# prettier formatWithCursor very slowed when use with *.min.js

Tags: prettier, min.js

I have an issue:
Use prettier to format the min.js file content, but the problem is that prefromance takes a lot of time if used:

```
prettier.formatWithCursor(contentFileMinJS, {
parser: "babel",
plugins: [prettierPluginBabel, prettierPluginEstree, prettierPluginHtml],
cursorOffset: offset
}),
```

Is there any way to make formatting speed faster?
please help me.